# Changing the location of eclipse folder

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

Hey I am working on an android application.My eclipse folder is in C drive but there is no more space in C drive. I want to change the location of the eclipse folder.How can i do it? Changing the location will effect my projects or not ??

Comment: <irony>it will ... that's why if you have eclipse on the other machine you cannot transfer the project between them</irony> but seriously, maybe, but nothing that cannot be fixed

Answer (score 0):

In general, Eclipse is resilient to parts being moved around, as long as those parts maintain their own integrity. There are two major parts of Eclipse that you need to be aware of and move.

The first part is the Eclipse installation itself - the program. You can easily move the folder that contains the entirety of Eclipse to another drive, and Eclipse will run as it did before.

The second part is the workspace - this contains information such as your preferences, as well as your projects (by default). This is a folder, the location of which you chose when you first opened Eclipse, and it may ask for each time it opens. You can move this whole folder to another drive. Eclipse, when starting, will ask for the location of the workspace, and you can now enter the new location of the workspace.

So, to clarify in terms of steps:

1. Move the folder containing Eclipse itself to a new drive.
2. Move the workspace folder to a new drive.
3. Open Eclipse.
4. When prompted, instruct Eclipse to open the workspace in its new location.